# multiple datatypes in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm building a predictive model to predict who of the student will pass the course based on the time they spent on each task in minutes.

```
Course   StudentID  Task1   Task2   Task3 ...
AA       3547       2       9       2
AA       3548       5       2       5
AA       3549       1       7       3
AA       3550       2       9       2
AA       3551       5       2       5
AA       3542       2       9       2
BB       3543       5       2       5
BB       3544       1       7       3
BB       3555       2       9       2
CC       3556       5       2       5
```

However, every task in every course is different e.g. if Task1 in course AA is a question and answer, it might be a video to watch or a wiki to read. I feel feeding the data as it is to the network would be inappropriate and just wondering if there's any way to sort this out. I thought of adding a column next to each task but that would impossible due to the great number of tasks and students. Below is the type of task in each course:

```
Course  Task1   Task2   Task3
AA      Q/A     Video   Wiki
BB      Video   Wiki    Q/A
CC      Wiki    Wiki    Video
```

Comment: That sounds like a great project. Could you perhaps clarify what your question is?

Comment: The numbers in task columns represent how long the student spent on the task in minutes, but the tasks are of different types (question, video, wiki). How can we encode this before feeding the data into the model?

Comment: To follow up on @NicolasGervais's point, there are many ways to sort/classify the data, but which ways will work really depend on your use case.  What does the function look like that you're trying to put this into?  What's going wrong?  Without more specifics it's too general (for me at least) to offer good advice.

Comment: nothing is technically going wrong, I build the predictive model and got the desired results. But logically, the data above represent different metrics and cannot be processed as they are. I need to find a way to classify them before re-feed them to the model. I've added a table of task types hopefully making the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say adding a column to each of the tasks is the clean way to do this. 
However if you do not want to add one additional column for each of the tasks, then you can have a tuple of each of the tasks.

The tasks tuple would be like (taskId, timeSpent)

```
Course  Student T1  T2
AA  357 (2, 22) (21, 14)
AA  358 (9, 33) (6, 35)
BB  359 (4, 19) (14, 19)
BB  360 (8, 34) (3, 28)
CC  361 (6, 9)  (6, 19)
CC  362 (3, 14) (5, 22)
```